# How to pass class attribute to child from parent in vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

talents. I want to create beautiful button for vue. But I have a problem. I want to pass class attribute to child from parent component easily.

Parent component is like this:

```
<!-- parent component -->
<template>
    <custom-element class="wanted-class">
        <span slot="custom-body">
            Some Effects or text
        </span>
    </custom-element>
</template>
```

and "custom-element" component is

```
<template>
    <div id="custom-element">
        Some elements or text
        <slot name="custom-body">
            Some default text
        </slot>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
 export defatult{ ...
```

I really want the root element in child ( $("#custom-element") for jQuery expression) to have "wanted-class" from parent. Is it possible? or it's too easy?

Comment: Pretty sure `class="wanted-class"` will add the class to the root of the child component

Comment: Thank you @T.Short